# OpenGL rotate and translate problems

Tags: opengl

I have an plane object, I want it to be able to move forward and rotate left and right. I want the plane to go forward in the direction it is facing.

This is the code I have, but it's not working, where am I going wrong?

```
    directionX=sin(heading*M_PI/180.0);
    directionZ=-cos(heading*M_PI/180.0);

    if(keys['W']){
        eyeX += directionX;
        eyeZ += directionZ;
    }
    if(keys['S']){
        eyeX -= directionX;
        eyeZ -= directionZ;
    }
    if(keys[VK_LEFT])
        heading -= 1;
    if(keys[VK_RIGHT])
        heading += 1;
```

The plane is rotated using heading, and translated using eyeX & eyeZ.

```
//Aircraft
        glPushMatrix(); 
            glRotatef(-heading, 0,1,0);
            glTranslatef(eyeX,eyeY,eyeZ);
            model.speedDisplayFaceNormals();
            //model.drawBoundingBox();
            //model.drawOctreeLeaves();
        glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: You should describe more clearly how it's not working. It would make sense to describe how you've chosen to orient your coordinate axes, as well.

Comment: Also, please post your glRotate/glTranslate code, or the code where this stuff actually affects your matrices.

Comment: But what exactly is wrong with it? Be more descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of a shot in the dark without knowing the actual behavior you're getting, but you might try switching the order of the calls to `glRotatef` and `glTranslatef`.

Comment: This is almost definitely the problem. In his code, it will first move the object to `eye` and then rotate around the Y axis that lives at (0, 0, 0), which if `eye` is far from the origin, will move the object in a huge arc.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenGL the Eye is at 0,0,0 and looking down the negative Z axis.  So, if you want to use and eye/camera coordiate based system then you need to do two things at the beginning, in this order:

1 - Rotate your scene based on the direction of your camera in your system
2 - glTranslatef(-EyeX,-EyeY,-EyeZ) This takes you to the 0,0,0 in your scene coordinate system.

You can then translate to the positions of your objects, rotate and render them accordingly.  I made some notes on this a few years back and this is how I did it back then when looking at The Eye coordinates representing the player location first person style.